# How to access a specific key-value from multidimensional array in smarty?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty, associative-array

I'm a newbie in smarty. Having problems in accessing multidimensional array in smarty template. My current issue is as follows. 
Following is may array named `$request` :

```
Array
(
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [teacher_id] => 97a056d0dd9e64b8daee46e6302409f8
    [class_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
        )

    [btn_submit] => Done
)
```

I've assigned that array to smarty template using `assign('data',$request)`. Now I want to access the values from an internal array `[class_ids]`. In this code snippet there is only one element, but there could be scenarios where more than one values present in `[class_ids]` array. What I wanted is the code which can access the values from array `[class_ids]` in smarty template. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by index:

```
{$data.class_ids.0}, {$data.class_ids.1}, ...
```

or with a foreach

```
{foreach $data.class_ids as $class_id}
    {$class_id}
{/foreach}
```